# How to create a new directory from Force Fortran 2.0

Tags: directory, fortran, create-directory

I need to *create a new directory* from my code to be able to write a data file to it.

I am using *Force Fortran 2.0* from *Windows 8* and I am also wondering if this syntax is going to vary from one operating system to the other due to the front/backslash issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force Fortran uses older compilers (`g77`, `g95`, `gfortran` [unknown version]), so I'll present a solution with `system`. For compilers that support it, it's better to use the Standard-conforming [EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html#EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE).

You can simply use `mkdir`, which is present on both Windows and Unix machines. By default, `mkdir` creates the folder and (non-existing) parent folders on Windows. This has to be explicitly given on Unix (`-p`). Using `system` you can execute this from Fortran:

```
program test
  implicit none
#ifdef _WIN32
  character(len=*),parameter :: MKDIR = 'mkdir '
  !                                           ^
  !                    The blank is intentional! 
#else
  character(len=*),parameter :: MKDIR = 'mkdir -p '
  !                                              ^
  !                       The blank is intentional! 
#endif
  integer :: stat

  stat = system( MKDIR // 'testFolder' )
  if ( stat /= 0 ) then
    print *, 'mkdir: failed to create folder! '
  endif
end program
```

You still need to create a routine that takes care of the correct folder delimiter, here is a quick&dirty example:

```
module conv_mod
contains
  function conv2win(str) result(res)
    implicit none
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: str
    character(len=len(str))     :: res
    integer                     :: i

    res = str
    do i=1,len(res)
      if ( res(i:i) == '/' ) res(i:i) = '\'
    enddo ! i
  end function

  function conv2unix(str) result(res)
    implicit none
    character(len=*),intent(in) :: str
    character(len=len(str))     :: res
    integer                     :: i

    res = str
    do i=1,len(res)
      if ( res(i:i) == '\' ) res(i:i) = '/'
    enddo ! i
  end function
end module

program conv
  use conv_mod
  print *,conv2win('some/path')
  print *,conv2win('some\path')
  print *,conv2unix('some\path')
end program
```

This doesn't take care of things like `C:\`, though... As @VladimirF noted, you can use `/` in Windows, too. You would still need to convert the backslash to `/` in Unix.

Comment: You can use `/` in Windows too.